# Lua - understanding setmetatable

Tags: lua, lua-table, torch, metatable

I am trying to build a `CNN` using `Torch 7`. I am very new to `Lua`. I was trying to follow this [link](https://gist.github.com/dangkhoasdc/34f06af0a9fd06320465). I encountered something called `setmetatable` in the following code block:

```
setmetatable(train_set, 
{
  __index = function(t, i) 
    return {t.data[i], t.label[i]}
  end
});
```

I understand that the second argument acts as the metatable for the table `train_set`.

1) Is `t` the metatable or is `t` just another name for `train_set`?

2) Whenever a function is used against `__index`, does the interpreter assume the first argument (`t`) to be a table (or metatable, depending on answer to first question)? And is the second argument always the `key` or `index`?

3) My understanding is that if I use `train_set.data[1]`, it will invoke the `__index`. The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026132/i-need-clarification-on-metatable-index) says that `__index` is invoked when `key` does not exist in the table. But is `t.data[1]` same as `train_set.data[1]`? If so, how does the interpreter know that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
setmetatable(train_set, 
{
  __index = function(t, i) 
    return {t.data[i], t.label[i]}
  end
})
```

Here we have some table named train_set. With this function call we set its metatable to

```
 {
  __index = function(t, i) 
      return {t.data[i], t.label[i]}
  end
 }
```

This is an anonymous table. If this is hard to read for you, you could also write:

```
local my_metatable = {
  __index = function(t, i) 
     return {t.data[i], t.label[i]}
  end
}
setmetatable(train_set, my_metatable)
```

Inside that metatable we implement the metamethod `__index`. By doing this we tell Lua what to do when someone is indexing a field in train_set that does not exist.

So when we ask Lua to give us the value stored in `train_set[4]` for example and `train_set[4]` is `nil`, Lua will go check if `__index` is implemented. If so it will call `__index(train_set, 4)` and give you its return value or otherwise return `nil`
So the interpreter knows that t.data[1] is the same as train_set.data[1], because he's the one who put train_set into __index.

So when you implement __index it will always be called using the indexed table as first and the index as second argument.

Answer (score 4):

First, two important links:

- [metatables](https://www.lua.org/pil/13.html) in [Programming in Lua](https://www.lua.org/pil/);
- [metatable events](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents) in the [Lua wiki](http://lua-users.org/wiki).

Now the answers:

1. `t`, the first parameter of the `__index` method in a metatable, refers to the table that **has** the metatable, here `train_set`. This parameter allows to reuse the same metatable for several tables.
2. `__index` is a **special** function inside metatables (look at the [metatable events](http://lua-users.org/wiki/MetatableEvents)), that is called whenever a field in the metatabled table is accessed but missing. For instance, if `train_set` does not contain the key `k` and you *read* `train_set.k`, there will be a call to `__index (train_set, "k")` in its metatable.
3. From what i can infer from the code, the usage pattern **in your example** looks like `local x = train_set [1]` that will return a table containing `{ train_set.data[i], train_set.label[i] }`.